# R - dplyr summarizing and cleaning a data frame with multiple groups

Tags: r

**Background:**

I large data frame that I'm trying to filter on, but incorrect groupings are making it difficult. Imagine you have a sales information for a grocery store with hierarchical categories. Banana shows up 3 times: 2 times as "fruit" and once as "meat". I know the "meat" sale actually occurred so I don't want to get rid of it, but it messes up my aggregate data I'm filtering on (say I only want to keep groupings with 3 or more instances, banana would disappear).

**Reproducible Example**

```
x1 <- c('a','a','a','b','b','b')
x2 <- c(1,1,4,5,2,2)
x3 <- c(10,11,12,13,14,15)
df = data.frame(x1,x2,x3)

summarized = df %>%
  group_by(x1, x2) %>%
  summarize(Avg = mean(x3),
            Times = n())
```

creates:

```
      x1    x2   Avg Times
1      a     1  10.5     2
2      a     4  12.0     1
3      b     2  14.5     2
4      b     5  13.0     1
```

The grouping (a,1) occurs more than (a,4) so I know (a,1) is correct (same with (b,2) vs. (b,5)). I'm looking for my data frame to become:

```
      x1    x2  Avg Times
1      a     1  11     3
2      b     2  14     3
```

`x2` is important for me to keep since my conditional formatting is based on that (i.e. if x2 == 1 & AVG < 10 then drop else keep).

Am I better off trying to do the mean/count separately and then adding on the largest x2? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to give consistent examples. While describing you explain it with "banana", "meat" and in your reproducible example I don't find them.

Comment: I noticed that you haven't accepted any answers for the 6 questions you have asked until now on SO. Please consider accepting the answers which solves your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** :

`which.max` by default selects the first maximum, so in case if we need to select the last entry with maximum value, we can just `rev`erse the `table` entries and then select the maximum.

```
df %>%
  group_by(x1) %>%
  summarise(x2 = names(which.max(rev(table(x2)))), 
             x3 = mean(x3), 
             Times = n())
```

---

**Original Answer**

We can `group_by` `x1` and select `x2` which occurs for maximum time, calculate the mean of `x3` and count the number of rows (`n()`) for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(x1) %>%
   summarise(x2 = names(which.max(table(x2))), 
             x3 = mean(x3), 
             Times = n())


#      x1    x2    x3 Times
#  <fctr> <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1      a     1    11     3
#2      b     2    14     3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! What's the default way which.max handles ties? i.e. when I add another row (a,4) at the end, this function still gives me (a,2) in the summarized table. Is there a way to switch it to pick up the last row if there is a tie (2 counts of (a,2) and 2 counts of (a,4)).

Comment: @CoolGuyHasChillDay I have updated the answer accordingly. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the most common `x2` within each `x1` group is the correct one you can do:

```
correct_cats = df %>%
    group_by(x1) %>%
    count(x2) %>%
    # Find most common x2
    top_n(1, n) %>%
    select(-n)

df = df %>%
    # Drop current x2
    select(-x2) %>%
    # Merge in corrected x2
    left_join(correct_cats, by = 'x1')

summarized = df %>%
    group_by(x1, x2) %>%
    summarize(Avg = mean(x3),
              Times = n())
```